# How to handle these two different strings using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
s='''“You'''   
s='''You“'''   
s='''"You'''  
s='''“You"'''
```

These are four different patterns of string first two are unicode strings and the third string is normal string and last string contains both. I want to remove '"' and '“' from each string i.e. I want to remove the punctuations from each string.

What's the simplest and most efficient way to do this in Python?

Comment: I want to see a short, concise example of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 s.strip('“').strip('"')
```

assuming I understood your question, this will strip all of them down to `s = 'You'`

Comment: Thanks Brad. For your answer.